# Does Google Analytics automatically handle URLs containing a jsessionid?

Tags: google-analytics, query-string, url-parameters

When a user visits my web site, the first page they load has a *jsessionid* appended to the URL like this:

`http://foo.com/Welcome.do;jsessionid=1234567890abcdef`

Note that the jsessionid parameter is separated using a `;` and not a `?` like typical query parameters.

Given that this is a fairly common pattern for sites with a Java backend, does Google Analytics automatically account for this somehow and ignore the `;` and everything after it?

If not, what must I do to tell Google Analytics to ignore the `;jsessionid` portion of a URL?

Answer (score 1):

Setup your Google Analytics to exclude the jsessionid

http://cutroni.com/blog/2006/09/21/google-analytics-configuration-mistake-2-query-string-variables/

> To force GA to skip certain query string parameters when processing we
>   enter the unwanted parameters in the ‘Exclude URL Query Parameters:’
>   filed in the ‘Main Website Profile Information’ section.

If Google doesn't recognize the bit after the `=` sign use Advanced Filters
http://support.google.com/googleanalytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=55461

Comment: I'm aware that you can blacklist certain query string parameters, but the jsessionid in my URLs *is not part of a query string*. Will this still work?

Comment: `jsessionid` is the parameter in the URL you're telling Google not to pay attention to it's just a string they'll look for

Comment: I disagree. "Query parameters" has a precise definition, it's the bit after a ? in a URL. So Google will treat the jsessionid as part of the URL.

Comment: @paulmorriss advanced filters can be used if Google doesn't identify the bit after the `=` symbol, http://support.google.com/googleanalytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=55461

Comment: That looks like it might work, if you use search and replace to replace the bit after the ; with nothing. Do you want to update your answer as the original question specifically says it isn't a query string.

Comment: Updated my answer